# Is it possible to use poison pill approach with bounded queues?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In Java Concurrency In Practice book (p.156), there's a statement regarding *poison pill* approach:

> Poison pills work reliably only with unbound queues.

Does it mean that with a bounded queue I can get a deadlock, or is it about some other liveness problems?
Is it connected with number of producers and customers?

Comment: I don't understand problem with bounded queues

Comment: Is it related with fairness?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a bounded queue, you could be prevented from adding the poison pill.

One way to avoid this issue is to make the bounded queue allow one more when a poison pill is added.

Comment: Well, every thread waiting to be able to add some item in the queue could be unblocked and the poison pill would still be out of the queue. Is there a standard queue implementation with a variable capacity?

Comment: Yes, indeed, but this goes only to non-blocking queues.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't know of any, it would have to be supported in the implementation to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Another way, (assuming blocking queues), is use an object pool for inter-thread comms and ensure that the capacity of every queue is greater than the total number of objects available in the system.  All queues will then always have enough spare capacity to accommodate a pill.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey and fact that **you could be prevented from adding the poison pill** a problem of Poison pills? I don't understand the problem. All blocking queues have fair policy

Comment: @gstackoverflow the problem is; once you remove a poison pill multiple consumers might not see it.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Brian Goetz writes that this technique will not work at all. independently on consumers count. Anyway I don't understand what changes if we use bounded queues

Comment: @gstackoverflow tcp is essentially a queue of bytes with a poison pill to close the stream.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, unfortunately, I am not tcp specialist, your example doesn't help me to understand

Comment: @gstackoverflow the point is. TCP works. Poison pills can be made to work with support of the library implementing the queue.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey bounded blocking queue?

Comment: @Peter I still don't uderstand what you want to say. I expect direct answer)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey according the book - the question relates only with blocking queues

Comment: @gstackoverflow the only concern I can think of is that a bounded queue can be full. Tcp is unbounded admittedly

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Brian Goetz writes that this problem  exists only for bounded queues. And my question about why bounded queues is not work reliably

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I think the best way to answer the question - provide scenario where bounded queue will not work but unbounded will work

Comment: @gstackoverflow that is the example I gave. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I ask java example) I want to see example where bounded queue will not guarantee work but unbounded -will wirk perfectly always.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey also your example doesn't help to understand why this will work only for unbounded queues.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the queue may be full at close time.

It depends on how valuable the data in the queue is at the time of closure. Can you afford to throw everything in the queue away?

When the time comes to close the queue it should be effective to drain the queue first before adding the poison pill.

```
void close () throws InterruptedException {
  do {
    // Empty the queue.
    while ( queue.poll(0,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) != null ) {
      // Throw it away.
    }
    // Keep draining the queue 'till the pill is swallowed.
  } while (!queue.offer(STOP, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) ;
}
```

but of course if the items in the queue are valuable you may wish to use `drainto` and preserve them.

Please also bear in mind that there may be more items added to the queue after the poison pill because not only might the queue be full but there may also be threads blocked waiting to post to it.

Comment: please explain problem of bounded queues usage

Answer (score 1):

@gstackoverflow: The main issue of the bounded queue is that it has a maximum capacity, so if your bounded queue is full, you will be blocked when you want to add this "Poison pill".

Bear in mind that **the Poison pill has to be placed immediately and cannot wait until the queue has some space**, as this technique is used to shutdown gracefully consumers when an exception occurs (otherwise there exists nicer technique to shutdown consumers).

**Edit**: As an example speaks more than a thousand sentences let's see a simple example (all credits for the example go to *Java Concurrency in Practice*), with a Producer Thread and a Consumer Thread:

```
public class CrawlerThread extends Thread { //The Producer Thread
  public void run() {
    try {
      crawl(root);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* fall through */ }
    finally {
      while (true) {
        try {
          queue.put(POISON);
          break;
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) { /* retry */ }
      }
    }
  }
  private void crawl(File root) throws InterruptedException {
    //some code
  }
}
public class IndexerThread extends Thread { //The consumer Thread
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (true) {
        File file = queue.take();
        if (file == POISON)
        break;
        else
        indexFile(file);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException consumed) { }
  }
}
```

Now when you examine the Producer Thread (CrawlerThread), you see the Poison pill is placed  either at the end of the run, or in a more dire situation, when an exception occurs.

Now let's say you want to use a bounded queue as the interface between the producer and the consumer, let's assume the queue is full at time t, and an exception occurs in the producer at time t, the producer won't be able to place the Poison pill on the queue and instead of having the Consumer thread shut downs, the Consumer will still be waiting for elements to come into the queue. Thus that's why the Poison pill approach is not recommended if you use a bounded queue, because it could potentially lead to an unexpected result.

Comment: Where did you find bolded text? Why thread always cannot be blocked ?

Comment: See my edit, let me know if it sheds some light on your question

Comment: are you about InterruptedException? This can occur in case of unbounded queue, anyway *add* to the queue takes some time and contention can occur also, I still don't see difference

Comment: What about other interruptions? If an io exception occurs because the disk is full and you have to wait 10 minutes to put your pill on a bounded queue, would it be acceptable?

Comment: any interruptions can occur on bounded queue too. If you want to add huge number of elements then occur contention and significant can occur on unbounded queue

Comment: Then I suggest you try the code above both with a bounded queue and an unbounded queue. Fill up the bounded queue and then shut down the Producer thread and you can see the difference in the consumers. I predict that in the unbounded queue case, your consumers will see the Poison pill, whereas in the bounded queue case, they won't see it go through (assuming you filled completely the bounded queue).

Comment: This behaviour depends on RejectionHandler

Answer (score 0):

I think the author(s) of Java Concurrency In Practice may be trying to say this:

When adding a new message to a full **bounded queue**, either the new message or one of the existing messages gets dropped. So it is possible for the application to continuously drop poisoned pills forever before they can ever become the next available message.

Logic could be added, though. For example, we could enforce poisoned pills are always added, and never removed. In which case a **bounded queue** may actually work.